# Use map() method in swift 2.1

Tags: arrays, methods

I have this code from Apple library and I am trying to understand how map() method works.

```
let digitNames = [
    0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
    5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"
]
let numbers = [16, 58, 510]


let strings = numbers.map {
  (var number) -> String in
    var output = ""
    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
    }
    return output
}
```

In the specification it is written that the closure calculates the
    **last**    digit of 'number 'using the % reminder operator and this digit 
    (which is var number) is used to
    look up     an **appropriate** string in 'digitNames'.

Why does it calculate the last digit of 'number' and not the first one?
   How is the 'output' string built?

My understanding is that
       First iteration:
   while number = 1, output = ["one"]
   and number / 10 = 0
      Because digit 1 is a valid Key in 'digitNames' dictionary, and 'number' is equal to 0
   "One" will be returned by the closure. 
  Now, the map() method is called on the 'numbers' Array and it will add "One" to 'output'

Does the map() method only add the return of the closure to the 'output'
   Array once 'number' = 0 or does it check if output value is contained in
   'numbers' before adding the return of the closure to the 'output'?

My understanding, even though it must not be right is that:
   for number = 1...9
   number / 10 is equal 0, therefore the while loop condition is satisfied
   number > 0 and the closure will return the 'output' as number + output and
   build "OneTwoThree". 
   So for

```
number = 1, output = [One]
number = 2, output = [OneTwo]
```

and so forth.

Could you describe step by step the flow of the code and how it works?

Comment: Are you asking about `map` or about the stuff inside the curly braces after `map` in _this code_?

Comment: @matt I am asking how **map** method works when applied on the closure it takes as its only argument.

Comment: Okay, I don't know what "when applied on the closure" means, but look at my answer and see if it helps.

Comment: I have understood how 'map' works in the example above. 'map' calls once each element in 'numbers'. The first element is 16.

Comment: 16 % 10 = 6, ; ["six"] is stored in 'output'   16/10 =  1 ;   var number = 1 ; on the second iteration, ["One"] is added to 'output' ,    1 % 10 = 0 ; The while loop ends its, execution and returns 'output' = "OneSix" , map adds the 'output' string to the 'output' array.

Comment: But this is why I asked you whether you were asking about `map` or about the stuff inside the curly braces in this particular example. You said `map` so my answer is about `map`. Now it turns out that you lied, and your question is merely about the stuff in the curly braces in this particular example. That stuff has _nothing at all to do with `map`_. As my answer shows, it's just a function like any other function. This is why I downvoted your question: you don't seem to know what your own question _is_.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @matt. However, I did specify that I was interested to know how map method works when applied to the trailing  closure that is taken by the map method as its only argument."  My understanding is that map method takes a trailing closure { the code inside the curlys} as its only argument and applies that code to each element in the 'numbers' array. I don't see how i lied in my original question. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: (1) I did correct you, in my answer. `map` _can_ take a "trailing closure" but what it really takes is simply a function. (2) I don't see what the question is, since the code in the curly braces in the original example _does_ take a trailing closure and _does_ apply that code to each element in the `numbers` array. If you know that, what more do you want to know?

Comment: Modified my answer to show that it applies to your specific example.

Comment: I didn't understand how each digit was calculated by the trailing closure. Initially I thought that the numbers.map would pass to the trailing closure one digit at a time from each element in the array rather than the whole element (16) to be converted to String and this is where my reasoning went south. Sorry for the confusion, this was my 1st post. I hope others will find our comments useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` method cycles through an array (or a thing like an array) and, for each element of the array, returns a new value. Those returned values form a new array that is the result of the `map` method. So each element of the original array *maps* to an element of the new array.

The way the `map` method knows *what* to do with each element of the original array is that you supply a function (often, though not necessarily, an anonymous function). The function processes an element of the original array and returns a value to give the mapped value for the corresponding element of the new array.

So, playing around in a Playground, you'll see that `[1,2,3,4].map{$0*2}` is `[2,4,6,8]`. Why? Because we cycled through the array `[1,2,3,4]` and our supplied function, for each element, returned that element multiplied by 2.

Perhaps it would help if I wrote that more verbosely like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].map {
    anElement in
    return anElement * 2
}
```

Or even *more* verbosely as:

```
func multiplyBy2(anElement:Int) -> Int {
    return anElement * 2
}
[1,2,3,4].map (multiplyBy2)
```

You can see that this is the case also for the Apple example. Again, it may help if I express the map function as an actual function and try it out separately before I use it *as* a map function. So:

```
let digitNames = [
    0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
    5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"
]
func wordify(number:Int) -> String {
    var output = ""
    var number = number
    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
    }
    return output
}
```

Okay, let's try it on a few numbers

```
wordify(16) // "OneSix"
wordify(58) // "FiveEight"
wordify(510) // "FiveOneZero"
```

Okay, let's use it in `map`:

```
let numbers = [16, 58, 510]
numbers.map(wordify) // ["OneSix", "FiveEight", "FiveOneZero"]
```

The result is exactly the same as if we'd applied the function to each element of the array separately, combined into an array — just what we expect.

Answer (score 1):

Map is a *higher order function* that when called on an array will produce a new array (possibly of a different type) where all the elements are the result of preforming a certain operation on each element of the original array. So we will take a look at its type signature (note this is completely over simplified so we can focus on map):

```
class [T] {
  func map<T, U>(T -> U) -> [U]
}
```

**Note:** its important you understand the concept of generic types in swift to understand this example.

So map is a method that operates on the array of of type `[T]` (which is just syntactic sugar for `Array<T>`). We can see that map takes a closure of type `T -> U` This means given one type it can return another e.g. `Int -> String` or `Double -> Double`.

From the type signature we can see that map returns an array of type `[U]`. So it gets each element from the original array and feeds it to the closure which return a result of type `U` which is then adds to the result.